# What is wrong with this data structure?

Tags: sql, database-design, data-modeling

I have been asked to describe what it wrong with this data structure, and how I would improve it.

Here is the data structure:

[image]

Here is what I have so far:

- The Car price is set only if the car is in the showroom, it would make more sense to put the price of the car in the car table
- It makes no sense to store NULL data in the Car Table, it would be better to have a layout similar to this:

  [image: Car table]
- There needs to be a quantity heading to show how many of that particular car are in the showroom as some showrooms have multiple of the same cars

The new table I drew up still has repeating data, which I vaguely remember is a no no when drawing up a data structure, and so I think I need to make a 3rd table? I'm really not sure.. .

I just need a bit of help as to what is wrong with the current data structure and if there is any way to improve it, any help is appreciated.

Comment: FWIW, you mean 'database schema' not 'data structure'

Comment: @Patashu: Schema is just name-spacing -- a collection of objects.  Structure is what the question is about.

Comment: we've learned them as being data structures, but yeah its a database schema aswell

Comment: Ok, I guess we got taught using different terminology then

Comment: @Patashu: Some database vendors don't support more than one schema, but yes - schema can transcend structure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One problem is that the Car table stores two distinct things - it stores makes, and it stores models.

So you should split that up, something like:

Makes: columns makename, makecode

Models: columns makecode (foreign key for makes), modelname, modelcode

And now showroom table will only relate to models, so it can't reference a make by mistake.

Since one model can have many showroom table rows related to it, you can't merge the two tables meaningfully, so keep them separate and go from there.

Comment: thanks a lot for the reply, i'm going to go with the 3 tables you suggested :)

Answer (score 4):

It looks like the Car structure stores both car makes and car models. That should at least get some alarms going. Car makes like Ford, VW and Peugeot have their own `MakeCode`. Car models like Fiesta and Golf have their own `ModelCode`.

In the original structure, car models refer to their make through the `ParentCarId` and *duplicate* their `MakeCode`. Car makes are not specific models and are assigned nulls for their `ModelCode` and `ParentCarId`.

The `ParentCarId` doesn't make any sense, what does it mean for a car to be a child of another? Instead, a car belongs to a make which is another entity represented by another table. Also, cars should not have a `MakeCode`, as this is an attribute of the make they belong to. Clearly, makes and models are very distinct and should be represented in different tables.

It would make sense to split that table in two: one for makes and one for models. Makes would have an `ID`, a `Name` and a `MakeCode`. Models would have an `ID`, a `Name`, a `ModelCode` and a `MakeId` (a foreign key to the `ID` of a `Make`).

Answer (score 2):

You're correct that repeating data is verboten.

I would change "showroom" to be "model" because there can be various subcategories of models.  IE Golf TDI vs GTI and such.  ...and the base price (MSRP) would be applicable to the model.  Show room status doesn't make sense for pricing - there's lots that are advertised but not In the showroom or on the lot.

I don't think there's any issue with having a NULLable column, if that's what the data supports.  Either is fine, and you can benchmark once you have a decent amount of data to see what serves you best.  But optimize after, not before.